# SQL Server IN statement isn't returning results when a variable is used

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I am stuck on what is probably a simple thing, but can't figure it out.

I have the query below which gives me the results I want - two records are returned.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_BudgetScenario
WHERE Name IN ('Sewer Pipes for 100 Years',
               'Sanitary Pipe - $5M for 50 Years')
```

However, if I place the IN statement parameters into a variable (which I need to do for the code I am working on), I don't get any results.

```
DECLARE @Scenarios VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Scenarios = '''Sewer Pipes for 100 Years''' + ','+ '''Sanitary Pipe - $5M for 50 Years'''

SELECT * 
FROM tbl_BudgetScenario
WHERE Name IN (@Scenarios)
```

It isn't obvious to me why this wouldn't work.  Hoping someone can explain and/or provide a potential workaround.

Comment: It **IS** obvious - `IN` expects a **list** of values - which is what you provide in your first example. In your second example, you're providing only *a SINGLE string* - no longer a list - therefore `IN` doesn't work anymore..... just because you have multiple values in your string, separated by a comma doesn't make a single string magically be a list ......

Comment: A workaround could be to insert the values into a (temp)table, and join that in your query

Comment: OK Thanks @marc_s - dumb question...  Is there a way to convert a single string with multiple values separated by a comma into a list?

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Yes - use `STRING_SPLIT` - that's what it's there for - available in SQL Server **2016** and newer (you didn't mention what *version* of SQL Server this is for)

Comment: Thanks @marc_s - I'll give that a go.

Comment: @marc_s  String_Split worked nicely - Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: I strongly suggest you use a Table Parameter, table variable or temp table, instead of `STRING_SPLIT`